# Problem with do-release-upgrade

Tags: apt, dpkg, do-release-upgrade

I am currently trying to upgrade from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS, but when I issue the command "do-release-upgrade" I get this message:

"You have not rebooted after updating a package which requires a reboot. Please reboot before upgrading."

However I have rebooted, more than once since I first got the message, so I'm guessing that there must be a file or configuration file setting somewhere that was written but not removed afterwards. Would anyone know what that would happen to be?..

Comment: You can do `cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` to see what it thinks requires a reboot

Comment: @OrganicMarble I think the file is `/var/run/reboot-required` (without `.pkgs`)

Comment: @Jos what I wrote is what I do (20.04)

Comment: That resolved it, thank you very much! both files exist. The reboot-required file is the one that prevents do-release-upgrade from running, the other one contains information on the packages that cause the reboot requirement.

Comment: would be worth putting in as an answer?